# What's the proper way to diagram a Django application file in UML?

Tags: python, uml, document

I have a python file, `rules.py`, that's a lot of functional utilities used through the application. Functions aren't contained within classes, and functions are called as needed from external files, classes and functions.

I started creating a UML class diagram (in Lucidcharts) with an empty attribute block and filling in the methods block (lower half) with the functions.

Is there a standardized non-class UML diagram standard that I should use or can use for documenting / diagramming long files full of functions? What is the standard I should use to document files full of functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UML is a collection of many different diagram types and many of them can be applied to less 'object orientated' type code. See the second answer here: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/302811/what-are-functional-programmers-using-in-place-of-uml

However, in truth, UML is mainly focused on Object Oriented software. If you want to use it in this sort of situation you can. But I doubt there's any sort of 'standard' for it. Just use the parts of UML that make sense for what you're modelling.